# Misleading tag [visual-studio-2014]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I've just come across the [visual-studio-2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2014) tag. Since there is no Visual Studio 2014 (only 2013 and 2015), I'd suggest to retag the questions to the correct version (if able to identify), or just remove it and stick with [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think they were mistaken with Visual Studio 14 which is Visual Studio 2015.

I would think we could just burninate the tag since we already have [visual-studio-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015).  If burnation is the way to go then I would also think we should get rid of [visual-studio-2014-ctp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2014-ctp) which has 25 question right now.  I would think both tags can be replaced with [visual-studio-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) if they are actually about Visual Studio 2015.

Update:

Both tags are now cleaned out.  Cross your fingers and hopefully no one will post a question so the tags will be removed.

Comment: Yes, probably. Since the internal version of Visual Studio 2015 is actually referred to "VS14".

Comment: Agreed, just make sure to tag with [tag:visual-studio-2015] if applicable.

Comment: Also, I would ask that you not randomly tag [tag:visual-studio-2015] if it's not specific to the new version. Use [tag:visual-studio] or ask for clarification.

Comment: Yeah this is basically [visual-studio-2011] all over again.